# Custom Input defined in TCA configuration not work in TYPO3 v11

Tags: typo3

I have a strange behaviour during Upgrade to V11 using a custom Input Element in the TYPO3 BE.
In v10 everything worked as expected. Now in v11 the type "none" in the TCA configuration will be ignored if a custom renderType is defined.

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['pages']['columns']['tx_awesomeicons_search'] = [
'exclude' => 1,
'label' => 'LLL:EXT:awesomeicons/Resources/Private/Language/Tca.xlf:awesomeicons.icon.search',
'config' => [
    'type' => 'none',
    'renderType' => 'plusAwesomeicons',
    'size' => 15,
],
```

];

This resulted in an DBAL Exception: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException
Unknown column 'tx_awesomeicons_search' in 'field list' changing page properties in the BE and pressing the save Button in the BE.Same behaviour if I add the Custom TCA  field to another table (e.g. tt_content)

For me it looks like the TCA combination of
type == none && renderType == "customRenderType" is not working anymore in TYPO3 v11
In the TYPO3 documentation is mentioned that "none" is choosen no data will be persist by the DataHandler?
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/12.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/None/Index.html

Is there a bug or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs for the none-field is said:

> Type none fields does have a default renderType in FormEngine that
> displays the value as readonly if a database field exists and the
> value can be formatted.

So i think you will have to use the type "user".

Described here:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/User/Index.html

Comment: I changed the type to "user" and added an additional (empty DB field). now it is working as expected.